# jQueryUI 1.13.0 Breaks dialog function in ASP.NET that works with jQueryUI 1.12.1

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

This uses jQuery 3.6.0. Wanting to upgrade from jQueryUI 1.12.1 to 1.13.0. This works as expected with jQueryUI 1.12.1. The LinkButton brings up a modal with information, no user input or interaction other than closing the modal.
Changing the library link to 1.13.0 breaks this modal- clicking the LinkButton flashes the page as if it reloaded/postbacked, modal is nowhere to be seen.

ASP.NET aspx page that uses a LinkButton

`<asp:LinkButton ID="lbRequest" runat="server" OnClientClick='javascript:return DisplayRequestDialog()' Text="Request"></asp:LinkButton>`

which triggers the function:

```js
function DisplayRequestDialog() {
    $("#dialogRequest").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        width: 1100,
        height: 900,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        title: "Request",
        overlay: "background-color: black; opacity: 90",
        appendTo: "form",
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

I'm not sure if a postback is unexpectedly occurring after clicking the LinkButton, that's a guess so grain of salt there. Open to all ideas on how to investigate what's happening.
I haven't seen anything mentioned in jQueryUI 1.13.0 bug notes.

Update (resolved): Thank you all for your help. Fortunately and frustratingly, the issue was due to using the Google CDN link for JQueryUI 1.13.0 (ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.min.js) which doesn't exist for whatever reason. Issue resolved by changing to a working CDN.
Delete my question if that's appropriate. Thanks.

Comment: The code as shown has no problems at all with jQueryUI 1.12.1 library.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, that is incorrect. Because of the `return` the PostBack will not happen if it is false, so you can have a Modal activated on elements that have runat=server. So the most likely problem is a javascript error somewhere.

Comment: @VDWWD you're correct - my mistake. I missed the `return`. As you say then the problem is most likely due to a JS error preventing the `return false` from being invoked. Open devtools and check the console for errors when you click the link - remember to have 'preserve log' enabled so you don't lose items when the page is refreshed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you see any errors in the Console? Can you provide a more complete example that includes the resulting HTML instead of just JS Code.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Fortunately and frustratingly, the issue was due to using the Google CDN link for JQueryUI 1.13.0 (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.min.js) which doesn't exist for whatever reason. Issue resolved by changing to a working CDN.